# VBA: Adding two range objects componentwise

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim objSelection1 As Range, objSelection2 As Range, objChart As ChartObject

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Set objSelection1 = _
    Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select first series", _
    Default:=Selection.Address, _
    Type:=8)
Set objSelection2 = _
    Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select second series", _
    Type:=8)

' This part is wrong
Dim objSelection3 As Range
Set objSelection3 = Range("=Sheet1!$I$56:$N$56")
objSelection3.FormulaArray = "=objSelection1 - objSelection2"

Set objChart = ChartObjects.Add(Left:=400, Width:=200 * 1.618, Top:=570, Height:=200)
With objChart.Chart
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .SetSourceData objSelection3
    .PlotBy = xlRows
    End With
End With 

End Sub
```

I am trying to write code that prompts the user for two data series and charts a new series given by the sum of the two inputted series. I am having trouble with creating this newly created series within my function. I've tried matrix addition (which doesn't seem like there's a convenient function to use) and formulaArray (which doesn't seem to take Range object variables). If possible, I'd also like to not output the newly created series on the worksheet and simply have it in the formula as an internal variable. I've avoided using any kind of loops because I believe there is a very clean way to write this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it, but the ranges need to be the same size.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim objSelection1 As Range, objSelection2 As Range, objChart As ChartObject

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set objSelection1 = _
        Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select first series", _
        Default:=Selection.Address, _
        Type:=8)
    Set objSelection2 = _
        Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select second series", _
        Type:=8)

    ' This part is wrong
    Dim objSelection3 As Range
    Set objSelection3 = .Range("I56:N56")
    objSelection3.Value = .Evaluate(objSelection1.Address & "-" & objSelection2.Address)
End With

Set objChart = ChartObjects.Add(Left:=400, Width:=200 * 1.618, Top:=570, Height:=200)
With objChart.Chart
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .SetSourceData objSelection3
    .PlotBy = xlRows
    End With
End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: Good solution, although I found another way to do this without referencing any unused cell (in objSelection3) by using arrays instead. Much appreciated!